# Is there a surface building function in ITK, which returns a VesselTubeSpatialObject?

Tags: c++, surface, itk

I just started reading ITK documentation and I'm looking for a surface building function, which can produce results semantically richer than simple `SurfaceSpatialObject`, e.g. `VesselTubeSpatialObject`. I want to extract lung blood vessels and bronchial tree, and I would prefer a data structure better representing these organs geometry than just a list of 3D points.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [TubeTK](http://www.tubetk.org/), which builds on top of ITK.